# Merging multiple datasouces for PagedListAdapter

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room, pagedlist

I'm using `Room`, `Retrofit + RxJava2` and `PagedListAdapter` in my app. The app should support offline and online modes. I have implemented `online PageKeyedDataSource` and `offline Room datasource` for PagedListAdapter which works well separately. But i can't combine these two datasources to make them behave correctly. Has anyone got ideas for that implementation?